# How to define labels and features for hyperparameter tuning of random forest?

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest, hyperparameters

My input file is under the form:

```
gold,Program,MethodType,RequirementID,MethodID,CallersT,CallersN,CallersU,CallersCallersT,CallersCallersN,CallersCallersU,CalleesT,CalleesN,CalleesU,CalleesCalleesT,CalleesCalleesN,CalleesCalleesU,classGold,VariableTraceValue
T,chess,Inner,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,Trace,N
N,chess,Inner,2,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,chess,Inner,3,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,chess,Inner,4,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,Trace,N
N,chess,Inner,5,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,chess,Inner,6,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,Trace,U
N,chess,Inner,7,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,Trace,T
N,chess,Inner,8,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,chess,Inner,1,3,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,Trace,x
N,chess,Inner,2,3,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,NoTrace,x
```

I would like to perform hyperparameter tuning for the random forest technique. I am trying to predict the value of the first column of my input file based on the values of the remaining columns. I am also trying to perform hyperparameter tuning of the random forest technique. The problem is that I receive the error message `features and labels not defined` for the following line of code:       `RFR_random.fit(features, labels)`. I don't know how to define features and labels as I have just followed the code of a tutorial. Here is my source code:

```
    import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import sys
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main(seed):
  
    dataset = pd.read_csv( 'inputFieldsMajority+MethodCalls.txt', sep= ',', index_col=False) 
  
    
    dataset['Program'] = dataset['Program'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['classGold']=dataset['classGold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['VariableTraceValue']=dataset['VariableTraceValue'].astype('category').cat.codes

  
    
    dataset=dataset.drop(columns=['RequirementID'], axis=1)
    dataset=dataset.drop(columns=['MethodID'], axis=1)
    dataset=dataset.drop(columns=['Program'], axis=1)

    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    
    row_count, column_count = dataset.shape
    
    

    
    
    n_estimators=[500,800,1500,2500,5000]
    max_features=['auto','sqrt', 'log2']
    max_depth=[10,20,30,40,50]
    max_depth.append(None)
    min_samples_split=[2,5,10,15, 20]
    min_samples_leaf=[1,2,5,10,15]
    
    grid_param={'n_estimators': n_estimators, 
                'max_features': max_features,
                'max_depth': max_depth, 
                'min_samples_split': min_samples_split, 
                'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf}
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
    RFR=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
    RFR_random=RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=RFR, param_distributions=grid_param,
                                  n_iter=500, cv=5, verbose=2, random_state=42, 
                                  n_jobs=-1)
    RFR_random.fit(features, labels)
    print(RFR_random.best_params_)
```

Comment: Maybe something is missing in the code you posted. There is no definition of variables `features` and `labels`. Please check the code and fix.

Comment: could you write those definitions for me as I am a beginner, the code from the tutorial doesn't define features and labels

Comment: You're asking me to teach a Supervised Machine Learning class lol https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py Let me suggest you to take courses in DataCamp (or other good platforms), you'll find there plenty of courses about Machine Learning in python. Before defining labels (dependent variables) and features (independent variables) you need to better understand what labels and features are.